# WPF Binding PreviousData not updated

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a `ListBox` in WPF which is binded to a `XMLDataProvider`. I add and remove elements programatically by appending and removing nodes from the `XmlDocument`.

In each element, I bind to a property of the previous item using the `PreviousData` type of `RelativeSource` like this:

```
            Binding ParentStatusBinding = new Binding()
        {
            RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.PreviousData),
            XPath = "@Status",
            UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
        };
```

When the binding is set the first time a node is created in the list, the `PreviousData` is set to the item's parent. However when an item is removed from the list, the `PreviousData` is not updated for all the items. 
How can I let the XmlDocumentProvider know to let the `PreviousData` bindings update itself?